# Accurate distance with GPS?

Tags: android, ios, gps, distance, accelerometer

I'm developing iOS/Android app that tracks mileage user has driven in his car.

Even though the task seems pretty trivial, there are 2 problems:

1) Mileage is not accurate comparing to car's odometer. (OD-10mi, App-8.5mi)
2) When user stays still outside the car, mileage keeps accumulating (it can add up like 4mi within 30 minutes.)

Is there any "easy" fix for that without adding complicated filtering, etc?

Answer (score 1):

There are two small but significant things you can do:

1. For each GPS sample, check its accuracy. If it's over some threshold (say 20 meters) - ignore it.
2. Add a method that detects if the mobile is static or not. You can do it  by reading the device's accelerometer - if the delta between two readings is bigger than some threshold - the car is moving. If it's too small - ignore the GPS. You'll have to try some values until you find the right threshold/

Comment: 1. helps. but does not solve it alone. (1+2).toegther  works but is more complex then neccesarry

Answer (score 0):

For question 1, vehicle odometer, in the US, are only required to be within 5mph of the actual speed at 50mph. My experience shows most vehicles are more erroneous than the law requires. That 10% difference could easily become the 1.5 miles you saw.

Answer (score 0):

Vehicles odometers are allowed to over estimate in europe by 7%.
My car has about 3% over estimate.

There are simple solutions, that work for cars, that have been posted here on Stackoverflow multiple times, including by myself.

There is no simple solution for pedestrians.

Answer (score -1):

Answer to question 2: problem certainly comes from the accurary of the GPS location.

Android *Location* object comes with an estimated [accuracy](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Location.html#getAccuracy%28%29) for the given coordinates.

Suppose you stay in absolute position (0,0) without moving. The android device GPS could produce the following *Locations* stream:

- (1,1) with an accuracy of 2m
- (-2,3) with an accuracy of 5m
- (0,0) with an accuracy of 1m
- etc...

If you just keep adding the distances between the successive *Locations*, the sum will indefinitely increase, although you don't move.

One solution could be that you take into account new *Locations* from the stream only if their accuracy is small enough compared to the distance to the last location.

Comment: Altough you explain the problem, your solution does not solve it. You abviously have not implemented the solution you propose